# Finding all elements in a JSON dictionary which are not part of another dictionary with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have to JSON files.

`a.json`:

```json
[ 
  { key1: "foo", key2: "bar"},
  { key1: "foo", key2: "baz"},
  { key1: "bla", key2: "blubb"},
]
```

`b.json`:

```json
[ 
  { key1: "foo", key2: "bar"},
  { key1: "foo", key2: "oof"},
  { key1: "bla", key2: "bla"},
]
```

My desired result is an array containing all the entrise of the first dictionary which are not part of the second one (equivalent to what the DISTINCT operator would do in SQL). So the expected output would be:

```json
[ 
  { key1: "foo", key2: "baz"},
  { key1: "bla", key2: "blubb"},
]
```

How can I achieve this using `jq`?

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: Nothing that got me anywhere close, sadly. I assume, that I have to use `--slurpfile` somehow but that's where I am stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't find a valid duplicate, so posting this as an answer.

---

If you use `-s` (slurp), you can use `object1 - object2` to get the difference between them:

```
jq -s  '.[0] - .[1]' a b
```

Will output:

```json
[
  {
    "key1": "foo",
    "key2": "baz"
  },
  {
    "key1": "bla",
    "key2": "blubb"
  }
]
```

Comment: The slurp-free alternative: `jq '. - input' a.json b.json`

Comment: Is there an advantage to making it slurp-free?